# finding specific characters in a specific location

Tags: worksheet-function

I have been searching for a way to find specific characters in the final location of an Excel string.

Example: 
plant
planted 
plants 
planting 
snake
snakes
snaking

I want to find a way of finding cells with 's'at the end of the string, but not the cells with 's' in another position, such as snake and snaking.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Formula in `C6`:

```
=(RIGHT(B6)="s")
```

[image]

**Edit** Comments:
This is very basic, actually. 
The text function `RIGHT()` 
returns the substring of its text argument,
counting specified number of characters (default=1)
from the right end of the string, so

```
=RIGHT(B6)
```

is the same as

```
=RIGHT(B6,1)
```

, see other examples:

[image]

And expression

```
RIGHT(B6)="s"
```

naturally returns `TRUE` of `FALSE` boolean value and is a short form to say

```
=IF(RIGHT(B6)="s",TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you add some detail for context too just in case another reader needs it for you answer to help them?